# How to get orders in NetSuite when status is changed from Pending Approval to Pending Fulfilment

Tags: salesforce, mule, netsuite

Basically am integrating Salesfore with NetSuite

Usecase: Create a MuleFlow to **create a Case in Salesforce** when orders status **in NetSuite** is changed from **Pending Approval** to **Pending Fulfilment**.

Question:

1. How to retrieve orders whose status is changed from **Pending Approval** to **Pending Fulfilment**.
2. How to create a case only when **orders status** in **NetSuite** is
   changed from **Pending Approval** to **Pending Fulfilment**.

Here is the configuration XML am using for creating a Case in Saleforce:

```
<flow name="case-creation" doc:name="case-creation">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="vmQ" doc:name="VM"/>
    <!-- Prepares-Collection Of Cases -->
    <component class=""
        doc:name="Prepares-CollectionOfCases" />
    <data-mapper:transform doc:name="PF To ListCase"
        config-ref="pf-to-listcase" />
    <logger message="Payload sent to SFO is:::#[payload]:::" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logs- Payload sent to SFO" />
    <!-- Creating CASE -->  
    <sfdc:create config-ref="salesforce-default" doc:name="Create Case"
        type="Case">
    </sfdc:create>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logs- Resultset of Case Creation"
        message="Resultset of Case Creation is :::#[payload]:::" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each record there is a "system notes" subrecord. You can do search to show all sales orders with joint system notes: field = order status, old value= pending approval, new status= pendign fulfillment. I recommend adding adate restriction to relative x minutes ago, depending on the size of the build.

I'm not exactly sure how you do that in XML, I normally just use a suitescript, its easier to find errors.